Problemas utilizando funciones asíncronas para el movimiento de un personaje en Unity
Estoy intentando programar mi primer videojuego en Unity, soy nuevo programando en este motor. Logre hacer que el personaje se moviera, pero quiero lograr que al ir muy rápido y al intentar ir en dirección contraria el personaje se tome un instante en frenar y luego continúe en la nueva dirección.
Mi código luce algo así:
public float velocidadMaxima = 10.0f;
InputAction moverse;
InputAction correr;
CharacterController control;
Vector3 direccion = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Vector3 direccionFrameAnterior = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
float velocidad = 0.0f;
public float velocidadFrameAnterior = 0.0f;
public float velocidadRestante = 0.0f;

void Start()
{
    moverse = InputSystem.actions.FindAction("Move");
    correr = InputSystem.actions.FindAction("Sprint");
    control = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update()
{
    ObtenerDireccion();
    ManejarSprint();
    EstablecerVelocidad();

    control.Move(direccion * velocidad * Time.deltaTime);

    direccionFrameAnterior = direccion;
    velocidadFrameAnterior = velocidad;
}

void ObtenerDireccion () {
    Vector2 entradasJugador = moverse.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    direccion = new Vector3(entradasJugador.x, 0.0f, entradasJugador.y);
}

async void EstablecerVelocidad () {
    await ManejarDerrape();
    velocidad = Map(direccion.magnitude, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, velocidadMaxima);
}

void ManejarSprint () {
    if (correr.IsPressed()) {
        velocidadMaxima = 15.0f;
    } else {
        velocidadMaxima = 10.0f;
    }
}

async Task ManejarDerrape() {
    if (Vector3.Dot(direccionFrameAnterior, direccion) < -0.5f && velocidadFrameAnterior > 10.0f) {
        velocidadRestante = Map(velocidadFrameAnterior, 10.0f, 15.0f, 3.0f, 5.0f);
        for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++) {
            velocidad = velocidadRestante;
            await Task.Yield();
        }
    } else {
        await Task.Delay(0);
    }
}
static float Map (float valor, float minValor, float maxValor, float minSalida, float maxSalida) {
    float r = minSalida + (maxSalida - minSalida) * ((valor - minValor) / (maxValor - minValor));
    return r;
}

Lo que intento lograr es que, si se cumplen las condiciones para derrapar, la función EstablecerVelocidad() espere a que la función ManejarDerrape() termine, y en lo que eso ocurre la velocidad estará dada por la función ManejarDerrape() para mover al personaje. La programación asíncrona es un concepto nuevo para mi, agradecería mucho que me explicaran cuales son mis errores.

Unity no se lleva tan bien con las tareas. Tal vez te sirva más una corrutina. Puedes hacerlo así:
IEnumerator ManejarDerrape() {
    if (Vector3.Dot(direccionFrameAnterior, direccion) < -0.5f && velocidadFrameAnterior > 10.0f) {
        velocidadRestante = Map(velocidadFrameAnterior, 10.0f, 15.0f, 3.0f, 5.0f);
        for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++) {
            velocidad = velocidadRestante;
            yield return null;
        }
    } else {
        // Realmente necesitas esperar un momento?
        yield return null;
    }
}

Al usar null, la ejecución de la función se pausará hasta el siguiente cuadro. Puedes devolver instancias de ciertas clases, como WaitForSeconds si deseas que se "pause" por cierto tiempo.
Para iniciar una corrutina usa la función StartCoroutine y StopCoroutine para interrumpirla. Por ejemplo:
var corrutina = StartCoroutine(ManejarDerrape());
// ...
StopCoroutine(corrutina);

También es posible que usar el sistema de animaciones te sea más útil.

Muchas gracias por la explicación, al final, seguí experimentando con las funciones asíncronas y logre implementar la función que quería. Creo que el problema era estar llamando la función asíncrona cada frame.
